# How to speed up loading data using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas and a Jupiter notebook. I am reading a 700MB CSV file, and it takes 69 seconds to load. For testing purposes this acceptable because I only need to load it once and it stays in memory for the duration of the notebook instance.

```
pd.read_csv(path, names=['Date','Time','Seconds','Counts','Pressure'], dtype='unicode')
```

I am trying to use the same code as a python executable, this makes testing really difficult because every time, I make a change to the program, I need to wait 69 seconds for the data to load. What can I do to speed up the reading the CSV file?

Comment: [The most (time) efficient ways to import CSV data in Python](https://medium.com/casual-inference/the-most-time-efficient-ways-to-import-csv-data-in-python-cc159b44063d)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could look into using `dask` [module](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) for this purpose:

```
import dask.dataframe
data = dask.dataframe.read_csv("your.csv")
```

Dask is much quicker than normal Pandas `read_csv` because it makes use of parallel processing and does not load the whole data into the memory. This [article from Eric Brown](https://pythondata.com/dask-large-csv-python/) is a good primer into potential uses of it.

Comment: i have tried dask, it is 4 times quicker, got it down to 15 seconds. i will try it in conjuction with the other aswer by using caching.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez Glad that helped to speed it up and thanks for reporting back with the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the parquet format, using

```py
df.to_parquet('file.parquet')
pd.read_parquet('file.parquet')
```

You will need to install the `fastparquet` or `pyarrow` packages.

Note that not all Python types are understood, so you will need your data to have standard types, e.g. numpy dtypes.

Answer (score 2):

I see multiple alternatives here:

- If while testing is enough to use a part of whole data, you can specify the `nrows` parameter in `pd.read_csv`.
- Specify `dtype` parameter for all the columns you are parsing and/or which dates to parse by mean of `parse_dates` parameter.
- Convert the csv file to `parquet` or `feather` format once, and those format will be faster to load in the future - they both require `pyarrow` installation as already pointed out.
- I personally never used the Dask module, thus I cannot say.

Answer (score 1):

Putting here another possible solution which does not require additional packages.

Basically, only the first time you actually parse the whole CSV; then you save a compressed copy of the parsed data on disk. From the second time you only load the cache.

This might save time as the decompression is CPU intensive but the compressed file on disk will be way smaller.

Something like:

```py
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np


def lazy_read(path, force_reload=False):
    cache = Path(tempfile.gettempdir()) / 'mycache.npz'
    if cache.is_file() and not force_reload:
        print('Loading from cache...', end=' ')
        data = np.load(cache)['data']
    else:
        print('Reading file...', end=' ')
        data = pd.read_csv(path, names=['Date','Time','Seconds','Counts','Pressure'], dtype='unicode')
        np.savez_compressed(cache, data=data)
    print('Done.')
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lazy_read(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin)
It is a lib that works with dask and ray, doing the same stuff as pandas. You can easily go from a Modin dataframe to a pandas dataframe and use pandas functions.
The module is still under active development