# How to read a very large csv file into a pandas dataframe as quickly as possible?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, timestamp

I am reading a very large csv file (~1 million rows) into a `pandas` dataframe using `pd.read_csv()` function according to the following options: (note that the seconds are also inside timestamp column but not shown in here due to exact copy and paste from csv file)

[image]

```
pd.read_csv(file,
            index_col='Timestamp',
            engine='c',
            na_filter=False,
            parse_dates=['Timestamp'],
            infer_datetime_format=True,
            low_memory=True)
```

My question is how to speed up the reading as it is taking forever to read the file?

Comment: You could try using `dask` as that appears to [be much faster at reading .csv's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58993719/19520503). I have encountered the same issue with loading 23 files at 1.6GB average and millions of rows but performance is not an issue in my case so I cannot help much but I hope that is helpful.

Comment: I'm going to post that as answer so that this question does not resurface every few weeks as unanswered, please accept if it helps or if not do not worry!